# Difference between Gurobi Lazy cuts counter and own counter

Tags: python, gurobi

I'm implementing a B&C and using a counter that sums 1 after each Lazy Constraint is added.
After solving, there is a big difference between what I count and what Gurobi retrieves as Lazy constraints. What could be causing this difference?

Thanks.

```py
Changed value of parameter LazyConstraints to 1
   Prev: 0  Min: 0  Max: 1  Default: 0
Optimize a model with 67 rows, 442 columns and 1154 nonzeros
Variable types: 22 continuous, 420 integer (420 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Objective range  [1e-01, 5e+00]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 1e+01]
Presolve removed 8 rows and 42 columns
Presolve time: 0.00s
Presolved: 59 rows, 400 columns, 990 nonzeros
Variable types: 1 continuous, 399 integer (399 binary)

Root relaxation: objective 2.746441e+00, 37 iterations, 0.00 seconds

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

     0     0    4.18093    0   20          -    4.18093      -     -    0s
H    0     0                      21.2155889    4.18093  80.3%     -    0s
     0     0    5.91551    0   31   21.21559    5.91551  72.1%     -    0s
H    0     0                      18.8660609    5.91551  68.6%     -    0s
     0     0    6.35067    0   38   18.86606    6.35067  66.3%     -    0s
H    0     0                      17.9145774    6.35067  64.6%     -    0s
     0     0    6.85254    0   32   17.91458    6.85254  61.7%     -    0s
H    0     0                      17.7591641    6.85254  61.4%     -    0s
     0     0    7.20280    0   50   17.75916    7.20280  59.4%     -    0s
H    0     0                      17.7516768    7.20280  59.4%     -    0s
     0     2    7.91616    0   51   17.75168    7.91616  55.4%     -    0s
*   80    62              30      17.6301180    8.69940  50.7%  10.7    0s
*  169   138              35      16.3820478    9.10423  44.4%   9.9    1s
*  765   486              22      14.6853796    9.65509  34.3%   9.2    2s
* 1315   762              27      14.6428113    9.97011  31.9%   9.4    3s
* 1324   415              14      12.0742408    9.97011  17.4%   9.4    3s
H 1451   459                      11.8261154   10.02607  15.2%   9.7    4s
  1458   463   11.78416   15   58   11.82612   10.02607  15.2%   9.6    5s
* 1567   461              33      11.6541357   10.02607  14.0%  10.6    6s
  4055   906   11.15860   31   36   11.65414   10.69095  8.26%  12.4   10s

Cutting planes:
  Gomory: 4
  Flow cover: 1
  Lazy constraints: 228

Explored 7974 nodes (98957 simplex iterations) in 14.78 seconds
Thread count was 4 (of 4 available processors)

Solution count 10: 11.6541 11.8261 12.0742 ... 17.9146

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 1.165413573861e+01, best bound 1.165413573861e+01, gap 0.0000%


My Lazy constraints counter: 654
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The displayed statistics on cutting planes after the optimization has finished (or stopped) only shows the number of cutting planes that were active in the final LP relaxation that was solved.  In particular, the number of lazy constraints that are active that that last node may be less than the total number lazy constraints that were added in a callback.  For example, Gurobi may add internal cutting planes during the optimization that dominate the original lazy constraint, or use the lazy constraint from the callback to derive other cuts instead of adding the original one.